# While rendering on openGL error code 138 is reported

Tags: memory, opengl-es, kernel, opengl-es-2.0

In openGL When create a new texture below error occured.

```
NCGSYS_FrameMemAlloc : AllocateAnyMemoryRegion (kernel) failed - 138.
```